# Infinite roots inside roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, roots, infinite-product

I was trying to find the answer to $$x\sqrt{x\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[4]{x...\sqrt[n]{x\dots}}}}$$ I eventually got $x^e$ but I can't find a notation to write that in so wolfram alpha understands it and I tried graphing it to see if it approaches $x^e$ and it doesn't.

So I think I am incorrect, but what I did is I put all the $x$'s in the sqrt
\begin{align}
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} ((x * (x^{(n)(n-1)}) *  x^{n(n-1)(n-2)} ... x^0))^{1/n!}\\
&= x^{\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{\left(n-k\right)!}}\\
&= x^{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}}\\
&= x^e
\end{align}

I want to know how I can verify the result, or if I am correct.

Comment: The sum doesn't start at $0$.

Comment: If the quantity in question were to converge to $x^{e\pm 1}$ would that be obvious from the way you graphed it?

Comment: $x\cdot x^{\frac12}\cdot x^{\frac12\cdot\frac13}\dots=\prod_{k=1}^\infty x^\frac1{k!}=x^{\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k!}}=x^{e-1}.$

Comment: I see, the quantity goes to x^(e-1) not x^(e) because the sum doesn't start at 0. Thank you!